# Creating Git branch in Azure, how to connect or check out in Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops

I created a Git branch in Azure devops, and selected to clone it in VS.  When it opened VS, it listed a git path and a local path.  When it loads, Im not pointed at the feature branch I just created, but master.

In VS Team explorer, in branches, I do not see this new branch listed either locally, or under remotes.  How do I connect to it and why wasnt it brought down when I cloned?

Is the preferred workflow to create a feature branch from VS, then push to the remote?

Comment: Can you run `git fetch` from the root path of your repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just needed to do a fetch so I can switch to it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/create-branch?view=azure-devops

Comment: the fetch command will update your listing of remote branches so that you may switch into and checkout a branch. That is correct. I wanted to note though, that you made a comment about cloning a branch. Cloning is something that you do for the repo as a whole. Branches are then switched into.